# Липкое меню на JS помогите организовать

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, меню

Добрый день.

Есть [сайт](http://privilege-spb.ru)

там меню изначально уже фиксированное, при скроллинге в нужном месте (скорее всего, так как js я не знаю) к меню добавляется класс с position:absolute чтобы оно осталось на месте пока не достигнет верха браузера; и дальше когда меню достигает самого верха браузера оно снова фиксируется прямо сверху и там же остается. Сможете помочь организовать такое?

Написал для начала структуру только:

```
<div id="nav" class="navabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#top">главная</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">о комплексе</a></li>
<li><a href="#flat">планировки</a></li>
<li><a href="#arround">окружение</a></li>
<li><a href="#gallery">галерея</a></li>
<li><a href="#callus">контакты</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте Майкл Миллер! Не очень понятно описание задачи, на том сайте вы уже применили правки(те что вам в ответе даны) или нет? Если вас результат не устраивает, то уберите правки с сайта и опишите более подробно задачу, возможно я скрипт напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы и описали - при скроллинге в нужном месте (в примере `offset > 300`) меняем класс на класс с `position: absolute`, позже, при прокрутке меняем его то на `position: fixed; top: 0;`

```js
function getBodyScrollTop() {
  var offset = self.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || (document.body && document.body.scrollTop);
  if (offset > 300) {
    document.querySelector('#navbar').className = "absolute-menu";
  }
  if (offset > screen.height - 300) {
    document.querySelector('#navbar').className = "fixed-menu-top";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", getBodyScrollTop);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.fixed-menu-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.absolute-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}

.fixed-menu-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="fixed-menu-bottom">
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, премного благодарен, а не поможете еще допилить скрипт? Не могу понять как указать место где меню должно перестроиться вверх браузера?

Comment: @МайклМиллер, наверх меню "уходит" во 2 условии, при достижении высота экрана минус 300 пикселей (screen.height - 300px), можете поменять это значение на нужное Вас