# как добавить/удалить класс при скролле в нужном месте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, header

Есть  тег `<header>`, который имеет свойство, **position:relative** и есть класс хэдэра *.header-fixed*, который имеет свойство **position:fixed**

```
<header class="header-fixed">
.........
</header>
```

Получается, что изначально (при закгрузке страницы) хэдэр должен быть статичный, но когда прокручиваешь сайт, второй экран (в моем случае это **#box1**) доходит верха браузера, то тогда добавляется класс **.header-fixed**. Вообще можно такое на js организовать?

Сам в js не силен, поэтому пробовал найти в инете что-то подходящее и допилить под себя,  пробовал так:

```
function getBodyScrollTop(){
if(come('#box1') == '1'){
$('header').attr('class', '');
$('header').css('position', 'relative');
$('header').attr('class', 'absolute-menu');
$('header').css('transition', 'all 0.3s');
}
```

И ничего естественно не вышло. Как понял скрипт такое как *"('header')"* понимает ни как тег, а как класс. Можете, ребята, помочь со скриптом как вообще такое организовывается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645741/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/645802#645802 что-то подобное?

Comment: Что Вас тут не устроило https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645741/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C? Добавляете только не navbar, а header

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Липкое меню на JS помогите организовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645741/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно повесить обработчик на событие скролла:

```
  var $body = $('body'),
      $header = $('header');
  $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        var position = $body.scrollTop(),
            block_position = $('#box1').offset().top; // расположение блока, от которого и зависит фиксированность хэдера
            if (position > block_position) { // если позиция скролла страницы больше, то ставим фикс
                $header.addClass('header-fixed');
            } else {
                $header.removeClass('header-fixed');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете при прокрутке страницы получить позицию `top` и в определённом положении страницы поменять класс для `header`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();

     /*Если сделали скролл на 100px задаём новый класс для header*/
if(height > 100){
$('header').addClass('header-fixed');
} else{
     /*Если меньше 100px удаляем класс для header*/
$('header').removeClass('header-fixed');
}

});
```

> Обновленно

или так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var box1 = $('#box1').offset().top;
         /*Если сделали скролл на 100px задаём новый класс для header*/
    if(box1 > 100){
    $('header').addClass('header-fixed');
    } else{
         /*Если меньше 100px удаляем класс для header*/
    $('header').removeClass('header-fixed');
    }

    });
```

Comment: Согласен, как вариант, но, понимаете, на мобильных устройствах высота #box1 разная. Поэтому тут не совсем подойдет данный вариант.

Comment: ну логика таже самая, обновлю ответ